# How to declare variable in EJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I want to display array results in my database on the frontend using EJS.

So I have the following code:

```
 var tagss = ["<%tags%>"]  
    <% for(var i=0; i<tagss.length; i++) { %>

            <a href='<%= tagss[i] %>'> <%= tagss[i] %> </a>

            </a>

    <% } %>
```

But error message keeps telling me that `tagss is undefined`

Here is the full message:

```
full message:


ReferenceError: C:\xampp\htdocs\meme.africa\views\pages\meme.ejs:171
    169| 

    170|  var tagss = ["<%tags%>"]  

 >> 171|     <% for(var i=0; i<tagss.length; i++) { %>

    172|         

    173|             <a href='<%= tagss[i] %>'> <%= tagss[i] %> </a>

    174|                


tagss is not defined
```

Please, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The stuff inside `<% %>` is JS. The rest is the template. You need to make it code, not template. Like you did everywhere else you used it.

Comment: How? Can you put it in code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can declare it like this

```
<% var myTags = []; %>
```

I hope it's not too late